# How can I enable the PDF bar in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

How can I enable the PDF bar in Google Chrome?

I can view my PDF files, but recently I can't use all the buttons such as Save, Print... my bar disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent [Google Chrome update (8.x) introduced Google's own PDF viewer](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2010/11/pdf-goodness-in-chrome.html) and it's enabled by default. They say it is more secure and always up-to-date, but it does lack some functionality.

You can disable the plugin by visiting `about:plugins` or `chrome://plugins` page and choosing to disable the Chrome PDF Viewer plugin. Which, at least for me, reverted the handling of PDFs to the pre-update state.